# Livewire the page has expired when setting properties or calling methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to follow the instructions given in the [Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts) to set livewire component properties or call methods in javascript. However, I keep getting "Page has expired" alert on Chrome?

```
<script>
            document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
                //These work:
                console.log(Livewire.first().foo)
                console.log(@this.foo)


                // These give the "The page has expired " error and freeze the page:
                Livewire.first().bar()
                @this.bar()
                Livewire.first().foo = 'Hello world'

            })
</script>
```

Comment: One would need more info here, but its in its essence not directly Livewire's fault. These are 419 responses from POST requests that Livewire makes. Typically that's a CSRF issue or a session issue. So the first two works, because it just reads a property from an object in JS, while the last 3 will fire requests (where you get a 419 back).